# Algorithm to create text on image repeatedly

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library

Using Python and PIL, I intend to draw text on an existing image.

I have an image that has 12 sections on it and I have an array of arrays as follows:

```
array = [
    [1,'ABC'],
    [2,'DEF'],
    [3,'XYZ'],
    [4,'aa1'],
    [1,'pqr'],
    [7,'etc'],
    [3,'klm'],
    [9,'bb'],
    [2,'aa'],
    [10,'xyz'],
    [11,'abc'],
    [1,'def'],
]
```

Now, based on the number in `a[0] for a in array`, I've to place the text of `a[1]` in the sections `1-12` of the image. I've tried this:

```
for a in arr_vals:
    if a[0] == 1:
        draw.text((337, 140), a[1], (231, 76, 60), font=font)
    elif a[0] == 2:
        draw.text((149, 62), a[1], (231, 76, 60), font=font)
    elif a[0] == 3:
        draw.text((337, 156), a[1], (231, 76, 60), font=font)
```

Now obviously, the problem that arises is that, say in the above example, `array[0]` and `array[4]` have the same values in the first index. This would lead to overwritten text in the image. How do I prevent overwriting in such cases? What would be the ideal algo to place text recursively over an image?

EDIT:

What I want: The text in red should appear in any of the 12 sections depending on the array.

[image]

Current image generated:

As you can see, the generated image has the text overlapped because of the same placement in the code.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? If you have both `[1,'ABC']` and `[1,'pqr']`, you only want the first one to be written?

Comment: No I need both `ABC` and `pqr` to show up in the same section. The issue I can't seem to solve is how do I prevent the text being written in the same area.

Comment: What's the difference between a section and an area? Perhaps you could draw a picture of the output you want, and the output you're getting.

Comment: @Kevin, I added the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organize your items into a collection that groups them by similar area numbers. Then for each area, you can render each line of text beyond the first with an increasing y-coordinate, so later lines appear below earlier ones, instead of directly on top of them. Example:

```
array = [
    [1,'ABC'],
    [2,'DEF'],
    [3,'XYZ'],
    [4,'aa1'],
    [1,'pqr'],
    [7,'etc'],
    [3,'klm'],
    [9,'bb'],
    [2,'aa'],
    [10,'xyz'],
    [11,'abc'],
    [1,'def'],
]

d = {}
for item in array:
    d.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])
print d

#d now contains something that looks like:
#{1: ['ABC', 'pqr', 'def'], 2: ['DEF', 'aa'], 3:...}

#height of a single line of text, in pixels.
#I don't know what this should actually be. Depends on your font size, I guess.
line_height = 20

color = (231, 76, 60)
for area in d.iterkeys():
    #somehow get the base coordinates for this particular area.
    #you originally used a lot of if-elifs, but a dict could work too.
    coords = ???
    y_offset = 0
    for line in d[area]:
        draw.text(coords[0], coords[1]+y_offset, line, color, font=font)
        y_offset += line_height
```

Comment: This worked! For the `coords` I just put if conditions based on `area` since the start position for each section is fixed.